# How to fix a corrupt Full-Tilt Poker player notes XML file

Tags: xml, corruption, poker

A recent software update on [FullTilt Poker](http://www.Fulltilt.com) caused a friends player notes XML file to become corrupt.

FullTilt creates two XML files for player notes; a master file containing **all** your player notes, and a time-stamped one that just keeps a record of any notes made during the current login session.

**Both** files became corrupted.

The time-stamped file was just missing an opening `<NOTES>` tag so I fixed that but the **master.xml** is a different story.

#### Here's what we see in FireFox:

[image]

#### Chrome gives us this:

[image]

1. The file will not open in any web-browser.
2. I am unable to open it in Gedit on Ubuntu or Google Docs
3. It **does** open in Notepad++ on Windows XP

After opening the file in Notepad++, you would think that someone had changed the font to WingDings, we just see a huge mess of random chars, hearts, arrows etc

We followed some advice that someone [posted on the fulltilt forum](http://pokerforums.fulltiltpoker.com/help-fixing-corrupt-player-notes-files-t105903.html) a few years ago where they recommend copy+pasting the contents of the file into a web form (*to fix the carriage returns*) and then back to notepad but I had no luck doing this. In fact only the first 50 or so chars seem to get pasted from the clip board. I suspect one of them is '*broken*'

So does anyone have any advice on how to fix this, I know it can be done, just got to find the right way.

Comment: seems like an encoding problem...it also could be encrypted, maybe you should have a look at a working "master.xml" and compare it.

Comment: thanks, I managed to do a comparison last night with a working one that I subbed into the program and there are no coherent comparable patterns between the two - the borked file has chars all over the place and the line structure has gone haywire